Definition of ervah
"ערוה" is the Torah's usual word for a forbidden relationship.
I remember seeing a Rishon, maybe a Tosefos, who says that the fact that kiddushin is impossible, that a permanent relationship is impossible - is the definition of what makes something ערוה.
Does anyone know where that is?

Tannaim debate if kiddushin is possible for chayvei lavin without karet, so you could say they are debating what is an ערוה but you first have to give meaning to the category ערוה that you are trying to define. Just saying forbidden relationships are forbidden is tautological.

Rambam defines ervah as a relationship that is proscribed on pain of Kares, as delineated in Acharei mos (Ishus 1:5). All arayos are impervious to kiddushin (ibid 4:12), niddah aside. If you're correct then that Rishon would not include the niddah as an ervah.

@Nahum, insofar as the question is "which Rishon says it and where?" i think you have an answer to that question.

@Nahum Rabbenu Tam seems to think Niddah, as a temporary prohibition, cannot be an Ervah (Sefer Hayashar 80:1).

@Ze'ev I first wrote it out as an answer but upon reading it closer I don't believe it is. Questioner is asking for a Rishon that defines arayos by imperviousness to kiddushin. Rambam certainly doesn't define it that way. It's actually difficult to believe that it even exists as then Niddah would be excluded and the Torah explicitly uses the term ערוה with the Niddah.

@DoubleAA Fascinating source. He actually deals with the issue explaining that altho the Torah refers to it as an ervah the rabbis do not (for hermeneutical/halachic purposes). I suppose that has R"T agreeing with the questioners exclusion of niddah from the category of arayos albeit for another reason.

R' Akiva holds any forbidden marriage is considered ervah.

These certainly seem like good approaches to the question (R' Akiva, niddah). I'll look in the Sefer Hayashar. Thanks, so far! It sounds reasonable that such a thing might appear in the chayvei lavin sugya where we have things that block yibum but aren't listed in Acharei Mos; if I ever did see it I think it was just a phrase inside some discussion.

@shmosel Does he? He holds chayvei lavin make a mamzer and can't have kiddushin, but does he hold they are ervah?

@DoubleAA See Sotah 18b
